# How to detect wrong URL using Joomla! System Plugin?

Tags: plugins, joomla, http-status-code-404, joomla2.5

I have developed a Joomla! system plugin.
I would like to detect wrong URL when that plugin is executed.

**For example**:

If I enter a URL "***http://localhost/wrong-url***", I want to catch that error in the system plugin.

How do I know that the system will display the error page (404)?

Comment: Do you mean in the front end?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following technique

**Check URL Function**

```
function checkURL($URL){
    $ch = curl_init($URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($httpcode != 200) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Use Of the CheckURL Function**

```
/*URL May be a Joomla OR Non Joomla Site*/

if(checkURL("http://adidac.github.com/jmm/index.html")){
echo "URL Exist";
}else{
echo "URL NOT Exist";
//JError::raiseWarning(500,$URL. " is not exists");
}


if(checkURL("http://adidac.github.com/jmm/indexsdadssdasaasdaas.html")){
echo "URL Exist";
}else{
echo "URL NOT Exist";
//JError::raiseWarning(500,$URL. " is not exists");
}
```

**NOTE: Check you have PHP curl lib installed**

Comment: I think he's asking about catching the 404 when the Joomla! app decides it's not going to handle the URL...

Answer (score 0):

In a system plugin to trap the `404` you would have to add a function from your plugin as a callback to JError error handler array.

I would have a look at the way `com_redirect` does it, with it's system plugin. e.g.

```
function __construct(&$subject, $config)
{
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);

    // Set the error handler for E_ERROR to be the class handleError method.
    JError::setErrorHandling(E_ERROR, 'callback', array('plgSystemRedirect', 'handleError'));
}


static function handleError(&$error)
{
    // Get the application object.
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    // Make sure we are not in the administrator and it's a 404.
    if (!$app->isAdmin() and ($error->getCode() == 404))
    {
        // Do cool stuff here
    }
}
```

The only problem is JError is *depreciated* so I'm not sure going forward when this would break e.g. it should be fine in 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 and 3.5 but after that who knows?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
If there are more than one errors with same level(E_ERROR), last handler will override others. So, system will use the handler of the latest executed plugin.
If my plugin is last, plg_redirect won't work. 
It is bad because all 404 errors are level E_ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I needed a solution today and found this question, so leaving my solution below to help anyone else searching in the future.

In the plugin file:

```
/**
 * The global exception handler registered before the plugin was instantiated
 *
 * @var    callable
 * @since  3.6
 */
private static $previousExceptionHandler;

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param   object  &$subject  The object to observe
 * @param   array   $config    An optional associative array of configuration settings.
 *
 * @since   1.6
 */
public function __construct(&$subject, $config) {
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    
    // Register the previously defined exception handler so we can forward errors to it
    self::$previousExceptionHandler = set_exception_handler(array(get_class($this), 'handleException'));
}

public static function handleException($exception) {
    // Wrap in try/catch to prevent any further exceptions being raised
    try {
        // Do whatever you need with the error
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //Don't make a fuss - fail silently
    }
    
    // Proxy to the previous exception handler if available, otherwise use the default Joomla handler
    if (self::$previousExceptionHandler) {
        call_user_func_array(self::$previousExceptionHandler, array($exception));
    } else {
        ExceptionHandler::render($exception);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: When do we get to enjoy your excellent contributions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange? (0 questions, 0 answers) :(